# Are we able to lock a folder or directory using java for a particular period of time?

Tags: java, locking, directory

Actually i will be copying files from a folder to other folder, during that time source folder should be locked .so that it will not be updated during transmission time ...is it possible using java ?

Comment: What's the problem with source folder being updaged during the copying time? You should define list of files to be copied before you start copying.

Comment: @jasper: And if you indeed want to ensure that *all* things from the folder are copied, even if the user changes the folder meanwhile, you can use Java to watch a directory for changes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html -- But I, too, would like to know if a directory can be locked. At least to prevent renaming/deletion.

Answer (score 2):

Java 7 allows doing this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html

Comment: This will be helpful only for the single file not for the entire directory right ?

Comment: As per @jasper, you cannot get a FileLock on folder or a directory, only on an actual file. (Of course, you could create a simple 'lock' file in the directory, and lock on that.)